# Rotate affinity values in a batch script for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, ffmpeg, windows-8.1, affinity

In windows 8.1, I'm converting my videos to **HEVC** using **FFmpeg**, using this simple batch script:

```
md hevc

start /affinity 0x7 for %%k in (*.mkv *.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%k" -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx265 -y "hevc\%%~nk.mkv"
```

I'm using the Start /affinity to limit FFmpeg to 3/4 threads, otherwise my computer gets chocked. It works fine, except it uses the same affinity value for an entire folder, and I'd rather rotate the affinity values between 0x7, 0xb, 0xd and x0e, so that it changes the active cores each time another video starts. I've tried putting the start /affinity in different positions in the command line, and I've tried running a loop within a loop, but nothing I've tried has worked. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming your inputs are H.264 video. If I'm correct, then why are you re-encoding to HEVC? It's another generation of loss and libx265 isn't very fast.

Comment: Yes, I'm converting from AVC to HEVC, because I'm getting files which are 2-6 times smaller than AVC, without a loss of quality, in my eyes. I've only just started, but my impression is that the higher the resolution, the more x265 outperforms x264.

Comment: Yes, it's too slow, on my machine it's 3 times slower than x264, but I'm not converting every file I have, just the ones I want to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a selection=0
for %%k in (*.mkv *.mp4) do  (
 FOR %%a IN (0:0x7 1:0xb 2:0xd 3:0xe) DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%c IN ("%%a") DO IF !selection!==%%c ECHO(start "%%k" /affinity %%d ffmpeg -i "%%k" -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx265 -y "hevc\%%~nk.mkv"
 SET /a selection=(1+selection^) %% 4
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should do as you ask. The `ffmpeg` lines are `echo`ed for testing purposes. To activate the process, remove the `ECHO(`

I've included a `"%%k"` after the `start` to act as a window-title as `sart` uses the first quoted string found on the line.

The process simply cycles the variable `selection` from 0 to 3, changing it for each `ffmpeg` despatched. The delayedexpansion mechanism is used to provide access to the run-time value of `selection`

Comment: Should that be `SET /a selection=(1+!selection!^) %% 4`? : )

Comment: @unclemeat: No. The `set /a` syntax operates on the current value and *doesn't* require `%` or `!`

Comment: Thank you both. Your solutions are impressive, but I'm afraid both are still missing a piece. I've run them and both scripts simultaneously start an FFmpeg process for each video in the folder, instead of processing the files one by one. Is there any way to stop the loop from advancing until the previous FFmpeg process completes?

Comment: If you only want to run one `ffmpeg` at a time, then you could add `/w` to the `start` command - but in that case, is there any point to specifying `affinity`?

Comment: The point of the affinity is that even running one instance of FFmpeg at 100% cpu causes other programs to lag and stutter, not severely, but just enough that it's annoying. Keeping one core free solves that completely, even if the processing is slower. Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: So - are you saying that you could possibly set up 4 parallel processes and avoid the problem, provided you specified a different affinity for each? You could possibly test this using the original batch but targeting a directory with exactly 4 target files.

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm saying. I use the affinity to limit the cpu usage of the single ffmpeg process to 75%, so it doesn't slow down other processes, it's not about running multiple instances of ffmpeg simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a little cumbersome, but it should do the trick.

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set c=0
set d=0

md hevc 2>nul

for %%c in (0x7, 0xb, 0xd, x0e) do (
    set c!c!=%%c
    set /a c+=1
)

for %%k in (*.bat) do (
    for /l %%a in (0,1,%c%) do if %%a==!d! set core=!c%%a!
    start /affinity !core! ffmpeg -i "%%k" -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx265 -y "hevc\%%~nk.mkv"
    set /a d=(1+d^) %% 4
)
```

An explanation:

The first for loop is so that you can have a dynamic number of cores. In this case, it creates four variables named `c0`, `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.

```
for %%c in (0x7, 0xb, 0xd, x0e) do (
    set c!c!=%%c
    set /a c+=1
)
```

Instead of using the start command in front of the for loop, I have used it for the ffmpeg command, this way each conversion will use a different core.

```
start /affinity !core! ffmpeg ...
```

The second for loop has a count so that it can keep using the next core of the four `c0`, then `c1`, etc. The for loop within that for loop just sets a variable which is the correct core (because you can't just do `%c!d!%` due to the way variable expansion works).

Edit: stole Magoo's little bit of math for the count.

Comment: Small question, I wanted to ask if there is a benefit to setting the core values in a loop, instead of directly with a set command for each?

Comment: @AlbertAmirGivol Not particularly.